# How to recursively delete directory from command line in windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

What is the windows equivalent of `rm -r [directory-name]`?

Answer (score 522, accepted):

<s>`deltree` if I remember my DOS</s>.

---

It seems it's been updated... this is what you want:

> **[`RMDIR /S`](http://www.computerhope.com/rmdirhlp.htm)**

This removes the directory `C:\test`, with prompts :

```
rmdir c:\test /s
```

This does the same, without prompts :

```
rmdir c:\test /s /q
```

Regarding the sudo part of your question, if you need more priviliges, you can first open a new shell as another user account using the `runas` command, like this:

```
runas /user:Administrator cmd
rmdir c:\test /s /q
```

Comment: For some reason there is a problem if you do this in Powershell. So just use Command Line of Windows.

Comment: rmdir /? will give you the full details of the command line arguments - S is "Removes all directories and files in the specified directory in addition to the directory itself. Used to remove a directory tree" and the other option is Q which is "Quiet mode, do not ask if ok to remove a directory tree with /S"

Answer (score 80):

If you want to delete a long and complicated folder structure from the command prompt that RmDir won't touch and not even explorer can display, I've found robocopy can be very efficient at removing the structure.
In the example below we have a massive structure inside the folder administrator, the structure is so deep that nothing can remove it.
We create a new empty folder called (strangely enough!) "new folder".
We then use the robocopy command, telling it the source folder is "new folder" and the destination folder is "D:\Administrator" with the /MIR parameter which means it will purge anything not in the source folder.

```
robocopy "D:\new folder" D:\Administrator /MIR
```

In this case the folder paths were so long they would not even fit in the command prompt window Screen Buffer, but Robocopy will traverse the structure and remove any "extra" files and folders (ie anything not in the new empty folder, which is everything).

Comment: This is the only solution that will work when your path is more than 250 odd chars long

Answer (score 24):

You can do the following in PowerShell, if you're on Windows Vista+ :

```
rm C:\path\to\delete -r -f[orce]
```

Comment: Windows 10 says `-f` is ambiguous. But you can run `rm -r -force <path>`

Comment: `rm : The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260
characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters` :C

Answer (score 10):

For me, what works is

```
del /s dir
```

You can add `/q` to disable confirmation. I've never managed to get `rmdir` working (on XP)

Comment: For me, this removes all files recursively, but is not deleting the directories themselves — `dir`is also not removed.

Comment: For me what works is first doing this, then finish it off with the accepted answer (which doesn't work on its own, sometimes).

Answer (score 5):

If you have a really really long path, (like I did because of java program error), even robocopy cant do it. It descended for about 30sec into my path and then hung.

My solution: if you can move the whole problem path from one folder to another then you can cut away recursivly and repeatedly some directory stairs from the top.

This Batch plays pingpong between the two directories leer and leer2 and cuts away 8 'libraries'
each time. If your path contains files, you have to add further commands to erase them.

```
recurdel.cmd
:loop
move c:\leer\libraries\libraries\libraries\libraries\libraries\libraries\libraries\libraries c:\leer2
rd /S /Q c:\leer\libraries
move c:\leer2\libraries\libraries\libraries\libraries\libraries\libraries\libraries\libraries c:\leer
rd /S /Q c:\leer2\libraries
GOTO loop
```

Answer (score 4):

From CMD Just run `RD /s C:\path\to\delete`

Hit `Y` to the prompt

`/s` ensures all the sub directories are deleted as well.

Reference:

- Run `help RD` from the command line

Answer (score 4):

In powershell:

```
Remove-Item "Path" -Force -Recurse
```

In short (nearly `rm -rf`):

```
rm  "PATH" -r -fo
```

Answer (score 2):

This will delete "my folder" without prompt:

```
rd /s /q "C:\Users\gourav.g\AppData\Roaming\my folder"
```