# What is the equivalent of rm -rf in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

As we all know, on a *nix system, `rm -rf some_directory` removes `some_directory` and all files beneath it recursively, without asking for confirmation.

What is the equivalent of this command in Powershell?

Note that the answers given [here](https://superuser.com/q/179660/196082) for cmd (using `rmdir`, etc.) do not work in Powershell. Though Powershell does alias `rmdir` to `Remove-Item` (presumably with some switch; not sure which), it *doesn't* alias cmd-style switches like `/s`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is probably what you're looking for. Seems like a little effort with a search engine would've reached the same conclusion.

```
Remove-Item C:\MyFolder -Recurse -Force
```

Or, as a shorthand:

```
rm <directory-path> -r -Force
```

(At least in some versions of Powershell you cannot abbreviate "-Force" to "-f" because it is ambiguous with "-Filter".) For more information see the `Remove-Item` [help page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849765.aspx).

Comment: Well, yes, I did try searching, but two-character strings like "rm" and "rf" don't exactly produce the best search results. Anyway, a bit more searching turned up [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1752751/1535629) - do you happen to know whether the `-Recurse` parameter is necessary, and if so, why?

Comment: Actually both are probably best. The `-Force` switch actually deals with hidden files and the like, while `-Recurse` deals with subfolders.

Comment: The -f is option is ambiguous (maybe on newer OS), b/w -Filter and -Force.

Comment: The only pattern that worked for me was `rm <dir> -r -Force`

Answer (score 6):

The closest command in Powershell is:

```
try {
    Remove-Item -Recurse -ErrorAction:Stop C:\some_directory
} catch [System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException] {}
```

`rm -rf` in Unix means remove a file and also:

```
-r, -R, --recursive   remove directories and their contents recursively
-f, --force           ignore nonexistent files and arguments, never prompt
```

[`Remove-Item -Force`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item) is not the same as `rm -f`.

> `-Force` Forces the cmdlet to remove items that cannot otherwise be changed, such as hidden or read-only files or read-only aliases or variables.

To demonstrate that `-Force` does not "ignore nonexistent files and arguments, never prompt", if I do `rm -r -Force thisDirectoryDoesntExist`, it results in this error:

```
rm : Cannot find path 'C:\thisDirectoryDoesntExist' because it does not exist.
```

A one-liner is `rm -r -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue`, but this will throw away errors that are not does-not-exist errors.

Comment: `-ea 0` is equivalent to `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` if you're optimizing for fewest (non tab-completed) keystrokes as with `rm -r`

Answer (score 1):

You should use an explicit `-force` key instead of `-f` because otherwise, Powershell would be at a loss whether it was a `-Filter` or a `-Force`.

`rm <path> -r -Force`

Answer (score 1):

This is the one-liner that behaves like `rm -rf`. It first checks for the existence of the path and then tries removing it.

```
if (Test-Path ./your_path) { rm -r -force ./your_path}
```