# Can't remove Node.js folder with Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, file-management

I managed to remove one Node folder using [this solution](https://superuser.com/a/179661) (`RMDIR /S`), but for some reason with another one I got many "the file name is too long" error messages and the folder didn't get deleted, so the solution doesn't seem to work well.

Also tried [this git bash solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22324885/delete-non-git-directory-in-git-bash-windows) to no avail.

I can't believe I'm struggling to perform such an elemental task. Do I actually have to do multiple command lines or install software to do *this*? Or is there some simple solution that very few people know about, if so what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
npm install rimraf -g
rimraf node_modules
```

From: http://www.nikola-breznjak.com/blog/javascript/nodejs/how-to-delete-node_modules-folder-on-windows-machine/

Answer (score 2):

### There is a way to delete folders with very long paths.

You didn't tell me where your Node folder is, so, I am going to have to answer you with an example. If you tell me the path your Node folder, however, I will update my answer with it. Now, imagine this path:

```
C:\a\folder\with\a\very\long\path
```

Pretend you cannot delete the `very` folder and anything below it because of a long path name error. You can instead open a Command Prompt and do this:

```
subst S: C:\a\folder\with\a
S:
rd very /s
c:
subst S: /d
```

The first command creates the alias "S:\" for "C:\a\folder\with\a". This way you whole path is now "S:\very\long\path" instead of "C:\a\folder\with\a\very\long\path". So, all you have to is to go to S: (second command) and delete everything in it. (Third command) Then, you can discard the alias. (Fourth and fifth commands.)

**Bonus trick:** Instead of running the third command, you open File Explorer and delete from there. Or do things that until this point were impossible to do.

Comment: Thank you but this is not what I call simple. I'm looking for something a lot more straightforward, because it's such a straightforward thing to delete a folder!

Comment: @drake035 Thanks to a bug that Microsoft is refusing to resolve, deleting a folder is NOT a straightforward task. Here, we give you practical answers. We can't do magic for you.

Comment: Sorry Fleet Command I truly appreciate the time you spent on your answer but it's too complicated. I found something way simpler: "npm install rimraf -g" followed by "rimraf node_modules" (http://www.nikola-breznjak.com/blog/javascript/nodejs/how-to-delete-node_modules-folder-on-windows-machine/)

Comment: No worries. I got ten points out of it and you have a way of deleting folders with long paths that aren't Node.js-related.